# Best way to add delimeter betwen text in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, methods

How can i add a symbol between the array of strings in this method? I tried using an if statement within the for each loop that added the symbol between each index of the array but it didn't work.

```
    public string addSymbolBetweenStringArray(string[] strArray, string symbol)
    {
        string s = default(string);
        foreach (string str in strArray)
        {

        }
        return s;
    }

    string[] strArray = { "Hello", "World", };
    string symbol = "-";
    addSymbolBetweenStringArray(stringArray, symbol);
```

The method then returns Hello-World

Comment: Try `String.Join`

Comment: Your loop is empty, why you expect that it works? Show what you have tried so that we can help to fix it or explain why your approach didn't work.

Comment: If you want to do it manually, use a simple `for` loop instead of a `foreach` so you can easily omit the last dash and buffer the result in a `StringBuilder`. Instead of `default(string)` I'd simply use `""` or `String.Empty`.

Comment: Sorry i should have inserted my code within the for each loop, my mistake. The string.join method worked, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method. For example:

```
string[] strArray = { "Hello", "World", };
string symbol = "-";
var output = string.Join(symbol, strArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Join`:

```
string result = String.Join(symbol, strArray);
```